# Поиск в ближайшего большего значения в неотсортированном массиве данных

Tags: массивы, excel, поиск

Есть таблица с котировками биржевого актива, которая содержит столбцы с данными: цена открытия, цена максимума, цена минимума и цена закрытия. По определенному условию (если цена закрытия меньше цены открытия) требуется в столбце "максимум" найти ближайшее значение, которое больше цены открытия данной строки, и вернуть номер этой строки по счету, начиная с текущей.

Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пыталась реализовать с помощью функции ПОИСКПОЗ, но результат получился некорректным. В данном примере т.к. цена закрытия меньше цены открытия, нужно найти в столбце "максимум" ближайшее число, которое больше текущей цены открытия (1489). При корректном результате это значение содержится во второй строке ниже текущей (1574.25), следовательно функция должна вернуть значение 2.

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно составить формулу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=МИН(ЕСЛИ(E2<B2;ЕСЛИ(C3:$C$99>B2;СТРОКА(C3:$C$99)-СТРОКА())))
```

Формула массива, вводится нажатием *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*, при этом формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками.
Это для *Excel*. В *Google*-таблицах формула массива вводится по другому:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF(E2<B2;IF(C3:C>B2;ROW(C3:C)-ROW()))))
```